# Failure to authenticate User with AuthenticationForm

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to create a TemplateView where each subclass renders an AuthenticationForm; *subclassing it and naming it UserLoginForm*. This gives the User the opportunity to login with their credentials on any page they visit and be redirected to that same page after being successfully authenticated.

When validating *UserLoginForm*, it fails to authenticate when it reaches `form.clean()` and raises `self.get_invalid_login_error()`. The TestCase used to simulate this scenario creates a User, then a POST request with the same credentials is sent. What's causing the *UserLoginForm* to invalidate the data passed to it and not finding the User?
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L197

```
class TestTopicListMainPage__003(TestCase):
    '''Verify that an anonymous user is logged into their User account'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        user = User.objects.create_user("User", 'secretcode')
        cls.data = {
            'username': "User",
            'password': "secretcode"
        }
    def test_topics_listing_login_user(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("topics:listing"),
            data=self.data
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "topics/listing.html")
        self.assertContains(response, "Logout")
```

```
class AbstractListingView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "topics/listing.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['topics'] = Topic.objects.all()
        context['search_form'] = SearchForm()
        context['login_form'] = UserLoginForm
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['login_form'](request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            resolver = resolve(request.path)
            login(request, form.user_cache)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(resolver.url_name))
        return self.render_to_response(context)


class TopicsMainPage(AbstractListingView):

    extra_content = {
        'heading': 'Questions',
        'query_links': ['interesting', 'hot', 'week', 'month']
    }

    def get(self, request):
        query = request.GET.get('tab', None)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if not query:
            pass
        else:
            if query == "hot":
                previous_days = now - datetime.timedelta(day=3)
            elif query == "week":
                previous_days = now - datetime.timedelta(day=7)
            elif query == "month":
                previous_days = now - datetime.timedelta(day=30)
            now = datetime.datetime.today()
            topics = context['topics'].order_by(
                '-views', '-answers__topic', 'posted'
            )
            topics = topics.filter(posted__range=(previous_days, now))[:20]
            context['topics'] = topics
        response = self.render_to_response(context)
        return response
```

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = field.label.title()
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = "login_text_widget"
```

```
> django\contrib\auth\__init__.py(73)authenticate()
-> user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
(Pdb) n
> django\contrib\auth\__init__.py(77)authenticate()
-> if user is None:
(Pdb) n
> django\contrib\auth\__init__.py(78)authenticate()
-> continue
(Pdb) n
> django\contrib\auth\__init__.py(66)authenticate()
-> for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
(Pdb) n
> django\contrib\auth\__init__.py(84)authenticate()
-> user_login_failed.send(sender=__name__, credentials=_clean_credentials(credentials), request=request)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> django\contrib\auth\__init__.py(84)authenticate()->None
-> user_login_failed.send(sender=__name__, credentials=_clean_credentials(credentials), request=request)
(Pdb) n
> django\contrib\auth\forms.py(197)clean()
-> if self.user_cache is None:
(Pdb) n
> django\contrib\auth\forms.py(198)clean()
-> raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
```

Comment: Apparently there's an issue using `User.create_user()` which creates a falsey password which raises the exception. Used `.set_password()` and everything passes now.